# How can I make a homing attack in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Basically I made a 3D person game where you can run around with a sword etc.

It is set up so that if you touch an enemy then you slice through them. I wanted to make it so that if you are close enough to an enemy you can jump directly at them so that you slice through them, like a homing attack from sonic.

Currently my plan was to use a near sensor to detect if you are close enough, and then when you press spacebar you would launch at it with a 3D tracking sensor. This doesn't work however, I have no idea why!

Also I have next to no experience with python, so if the solution involves python then please try to explain it as if I am a 3 year old. Also if their is a way to do it with logic bricks, then I will definitely use the logic bricks even if it is more complicated.